# How to salvage my Visual Studio 2013 project from a working .exe build?

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2013, corrupt, recover

My project is a Windows Forms Application, written in C#. 
While I was working on it, VS stopped responding, and finally my laptop crashed.
The next time I ran the Solution of my project, the Form1.cs file was corrupted and empty.
I cracked the .exe build using ILSpy, I got the Form1 code back, although it has a different structure and all comments missing etc...
But I can't seem to find the Design file where I created my Form layout. Note that I have the Design file from my corrupted project, but my files don't seem to adapt to each other.

Summary: I have a "working" .cs file of my Form, and the Design of the corrupted form, in addition to a working .exe build

Question: How can I get the project to be working again?

PS: Note that the backup file of VS is empty.

Comment: try dotPeek to get some code back

Comment: dotpeek is the way to go.

Comment: This is why you should use version control even for simply stuff.

Answer (score 1):

ILSpy is a free opensource tool that can export a full project.